# How do we feel about answers that automate unlocking a Steam achievement?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

[Party Hard](http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/356570/) has an achievement for launching the game 100 times. Not content with launching the game 100 times manually just to get the achievement, I wrote a batch script that makes use of the [Steam Browser Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) to launch the game, and kill it again with some batch-fu (Which, ironically, I honestly feel like I've put in enough effort to have rightfully '*earned*' the achievement!)

I'd like to share this script and explain how it works on a question about how to 'earn' the achievement, however I'm guessing there are probably a few out there who will balk at the automation or 'workaround' method.

My question is: Is this sort of question/answer something we 'like' here? Do we support the automation or 'workaround' methods of earning achievements?

Comment: Single player cheats are fine by us

Comment: @badp - Sure, but it's a single player cheat with ramifications for Steam's achievement tracking, I had to be sure :)

Comment: Plenty of cheats can be used to earn achievements! They still only affect you.

Comment: @badp - ok you've convinced me, here it is: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/240676/28182

Comment: I think is is rather creative and allows users to have an alternative to the known options of completing the achievement.

Comment: Universe Sandbox has achievements such as those that involve starting the game up 10, 100, 1000, 10000 and 100000 times. You'd have no other choice *but* to use a batch script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There should really be no problem with what you are suggesting. It is likely that some users will not like your solution, feeling that the trick is unfair, but ultimately this sort of question/answer is not off topic in any way. Furthermore, it sounds like you solution could solve a great annoyance, for achievement hunters that feel such a tedious task is pointless and annoying.

At the end of the day, the only reason I could see people voting against this would be the possible belief that this could put the user at risk of a ban with steam. Ultimately, since Steam has provided you access to the protocol, you are not accessing it iligitimately nor breaking any rules.

"Achievement cheating", as some may call it, is often considered acceptable by the head company. As such, games like [Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/do-console-commands-affect-steam-achievements) allow achievements to be unlocked even after the player uses console commands to make the process significantly easier. As another example, [Fallout 3](http://www.trueachievements.com/Fallout-3-PC/walkthrough.htm?page=3) allows the player to legitimately unlock its entire achievement list via the console command.

Unless you are engaging in a method that is deliberately disallowed by Steam, the solution you suggest should definitely be posted for other users engaging the same problem further down the line.

Comment: I suggest that the OP posts a link to this discussion in the comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: @angussidney - Way ahead o' ya, chief :-)

Comment: "Furthermore, it sounds like you solution could solve a great annoyance, for achievement hunters that feel such a tedious task is pointless and annoying." But that's the poooooooint. =[

Comment: @GnomeSlice - Well, I felt that the achievement was pointless and annoying, so I looked for a novel way to solve it. It suddenly *felt* like an achievement earning it that way :)